# Using a contour integral of $f(z)=x^{4n+3}e^{-z}$ to show $\int_0^\infty x^{4n+3}e^{-x}\cos x\;dx=(-1)^{n+1}(4n+3)!/2^{2n+2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am pretty close to finding the right-hand side of the desired proof (see below) but not able to finish it.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSsgH.png]

I have done this far but, it seems too long to continue.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcIUZ.png]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: The integrand decays exponentially on $C_2$ when the radius increases. Then we know that the imaginary part of $I_3$ is zero and we need to extract only the real part of the integrand, which is $(-1)^{n - 1} t^{4 n + 3}$ times
$$\operatorname {Re} \exp(-e^{\pi i/4} t) =
e^{-t/\sqrt 2} \cos \frac t {\sqrt 2}.$$
$u = t/\sqrt 2$ will give the desired formula.